# How to migrate own question

Tags: support

I asked [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69406/which-map-background-color-is-best-from-the-perspective-of-ergonomics-at-the-wo) on gis.stackexchange. Now I want to migrate it to [ux.stackexchange.com](https://ux.stackexchange.com/)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should Flag your question for Moderator attention under the Other category which will let you enter text including the site you would like it migrated to.